# Webhook for Google Forms to post submissions to a Discord channel

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, discord

I have a problem with a Webhook for Google Forms to post submissions to a Discord channel. It works great but I don't want it to fetch the entire submission but only the first 4 responses. [GitHub link to code](https://gist.github.com/dieter007/a1ceab5bc527b72907b809e4234221a5)

```
var POST_URL = "WEBHOOKURL";

function onSubmit(e) {
 var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
 var allResponses = form.getResponses();
 var latestResponse = allResponses[allResponses.length - 1];
 var response = latestResponse.getItemResponses();
 var items = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  var question = response[i].getItem().getTitle();
  var answer = response[i].getResponse();
  var parts = answer.match(/[\s\S]{1,1024}/g) || [];

  if (answer == "") {
   continue;
}
for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
 if (j == 0) {
  items.push({
   "name": question,
   "value": parts[j],
   "inline": false
  });
 } else {
  items.push({
   "name": question.concat(" (cont.)"),
   "value": parts[j],
   "inline": false
  });
 }
}
}

var options = {
 "method": "post",
 "payload": JSON.stringify({
  "embeds": [{
   "title": "TOP TEXT CHANGE THIS IN SCRIPT",
   "fields": items,
   "footer": {
    "text": "BOTTOM TEXT CHANGE THIS IN SCRIPT"
   }
  }]
 })
};

UrlFetchApp.fetch(POST_URL, options);
};
```

I have already tried the following edit in line 5

```
var allResponses = form.getResponses().slice(0, 4);
```

and it didn't work. It just fetched the entire form.

I hope someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: Please, post test as (formatted) text, not as a picture.

Comment: As per request changed from screenshot to formatted text. I hope that clarifies the problem.

Comment: I've also added a link with the entire script. An idea would be that if allResponses = [response1, response2, response3, response4], then allResponses[1:3] will return [response2, response3]. But I don't know if that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it. If I change line 11 to

`for (var i = 0; i < response.length - ?; i++) {`

with ? being the number of responses that you want to have omitted you get the desired result.
There may be a way to do it in the earlier lines but this has worked for me.

Comment: If this is your solution, you may want to actually accept it.